# Validating custom validators depending on other validators present

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

After practicing custom hibernate validators for now, I wanted to explore more. As we all know, a custom hibernate annotation can be validated by one or more `ConstraintValidator<T extends Annotation, X>` depending on the data type of `X`.

I was wondering if I could create several `ConstraintValidator` (for `@FooOne`) which would be selected depending on the paired constraint validators (`@FooTwo` and `@FooThree`) in a particular bean class. For example:

```
@FooOne
@FooTwo
private String fooField;

@FooOne
@FooThree
private String anotherFooField;
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. This would violate the "ConstraintValidator resolution algorithm". See also the Bean Validation specification - http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#typevalidatorresolution.

There is an exception thrown if there are more than two (maximally specific) constraint validator implementations for the same type.

Comment: I see. Yet, would there be any alternatives?

Comment: It depends on your use case. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Basically, I wanted to the custom annotation to invoke one `ConstraintValidator` from its list of validators in which the selected validator is selected if another particular custom annotation is added. It's like `@FooOne` would invoke `FooOneFooTwoValidator` for the case of `fooField` and invoke `FooOneFooTwoValidator` for `anotherField`.

Comment: Sure, the question is what use case you want to solve. Why do you want to have this conditional constraint validator selection. Also, remember the whole idea of constraints is that they are independent. If your case were possible it would be very hard to determine what validation actually occurs. If you want to combine constraints, you might be interested in constraint composition, but again, it will depend on the use case you want to solve.